# Como incluir os finais de semana na função "=Diatrabalho" e incluir feriados adicionais no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma data de inicio e de termino de um cronograma, eu queria contar os finais de semana que no caso a data final seria 11/11/2018, como usar a função:

`=DIATRABALHO(C24;E24;Tabela1[DATA])`

Para contar com os finais de semana?

Também seria possível adicionar feriados adicionais? Além dos obrigatórios?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função:

```
=DIATRABALHO.INTL(data inicial; dias;[fimdesemana], [feriados])
```

Em fim de semana, você pode informar o que você considera esse fim de semana. Se é sábado ou domingo (1) ou outras opções.

O Excel, em versões mais novas, irá mostrar as opções que você pode inforar em [fimdesemana]. Utilize a mesma fórmula, porém utilizando o parâmetro do fimdesemana.

```
=DIATRABALHO.INTL(C24;E24;1;Tabela1[DATA])
```

Observe o número 1 na função acima.

Porém, no seu caso, você pode ignorar as opções que tem lá e usar assim:

```
 =DIATRABALHO.INTL(C24;E24;"0000000";Tabela1[DATA])
```

Se a resposta estiver dando um dia a mais, faça isso: subtraia -1.

```
=DIATRABALHO.INTL(C24;E24;"0000000";Tabela1[DATA])-1
```

Comment: Ele ainda bateu até o dia 16, não sei porque, era para ir até o dia 11

Comment: Fiz de forma correta a formula =DIATRABALHO.INTL(C24;E24;1;Tabela2[DATA])

Comment: fiz outra atualização.

Comment: Não cai dia 11, caiu dia 12, tentei subtrair colocando 6 zeros e mesmo assim não foi, tentei por -1 em diferentes locais, mas da erro

Comment: eu esqueci de mostrar onde vc subtrai por menos 1. veja agora